# Nic bond issues

Tags: networking, network-bonding

Encountering an issue when trying to bond two nics in a HP server running 22.04.

I'm using the following netplan config file and two ports on the cisco switch bonded with LACP, the ports on the cisco switch come up as suspended when bond0 is brought up.

```
network:

  version: 2

  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:

    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
    eno2:
      dhcp4: false
    eno3:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 172.18.16.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [172.18.10.250, 172.18.10.251]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 172.18.16.254
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
    eno49:
      dhcp4: true
    eno50:
      dhcp4: true
    ens3f0:
      dhcp4: true
    ens3f1:
      dhcp4: true
    ens3f2:
      dhcp4: true
    ens3f3:
      dhcp4: true
  bonds:

    bond0:
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - eno2
      addresses: [172.18.16.17/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [172.18.10.250, 172.18.10.251]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 172.18.16.254
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        mii-monitor-interval: 1
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Your question is unclear of how this deals with Ubuntu and what version you are using.  Also, your information that you have posted is not exact.  Please make sure that when you post code information from a file that it is formatted correctly.  Make sure to test your config as well.  See: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/netplan-try.8.html Also make sure that your switch is configured properly to support LACP and that you have no failures of the bond configured.  See: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2sb/feature/guide/gigeth.html#wp1078429

Comment: I'm using mostly the same config for creating a bond myself to a UniFi Switch - the only difference is I don't have the `mii-monitor-interval: 1` line - and this works fine for me. Are you sure the ports are configured as aggregate on the Cisco Switch as well?